# EF Core seeing one to many and many to many null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to seed data and none of my mappings seem to be working. I believe I am following the [textbook examples ][1] from documentation but I must be missing something.

My classes

```cs
    public class HighSchoolRegistrationModel
    {
        public long Id{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string SchoolEmail { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CourseModel> CourseModelsOffered { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }

    public class Student
    {
        public long StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long HighSchoolRegistrationModelId { get; set; }
        public HighSchoolRegistrationModel HighSchoolRegistrationModel { get; set; }
        public Grade CurrentGradeLevel { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CourseInstance> Courses { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CourseGrade> CourseGrades { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ReportCard> ReportCards { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public long ResultId{ get; set; }
        public long StudentId { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public Exam ExamType { get; set; }
        public double Score { get; set; }
    }
```

My context class

```cs
        // HighSchoolContext, my only context
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<HighSchoolRegistrationModel>().HasData(
                new HighSchoolRegistrationModel 
                { 
                    Id = 1, 
                    SchoolName = "Nouveau Blaise Pascal", 
                    Address = "123 Rue du Ciel",
                    SchoolEmail = "npb@fauxemails.fr"
                }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<CourseModel>().HasData(
                new CourseModel()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    CourseName = "Maths",
                    GradeLevel = Grade.Fifth,
                    HighSchoolRegistrationModelId = 1
                },
                new CourseModel()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    CourseName = "Language",
                    GradeLevel = Grade.Fifth,
                    HighSchoolRegistrationModelId = 1
                }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasData(
                new Student() 
                { 
                    StudentId = 1, 
                    Name = "Camille Foussoulou",
                    CurrentGradeLevel = Grade.Fifth,
                    HighSchoolRegistrationModelId = 1
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    StudentId = 2,
                    Name = "Lucas Foussoulou",
                    CurrentGradeLevel = Grade.Fifth,
                    HighSchoolRegistrationModelId = 1
                }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Guardian>().HasData(
                new Guardian()
                {
                    GuardianId = 1,
                    Name = "Joseph Foussoulou"
                },
                new Guardian()
                {
                    GuardianId = 2,
                    Name = "Jeanne Ntoume"
                }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<GuardianStudent>().HasData(
                new GuardianStudent() { GuardianId = 1, StudentId = 1},
                new GuardianStudent() { GuardianId = 1, StudentId = 2},
                new GuardianStudent() { GuardianId = 2, StudentId = 1},
                new GuardianStudent() { GuardianId = 2, StudentId = 2}
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Result>().HasData(
                new Result()
                {
                    ResultId = 1,
                    StudentId = 1,
                    ExamType = Exam.Art,
                    Score = 77.7
                },
                new Result()
                {
                    ResultId = 2,
                    StudentId = 1,
                    ExamType = Exam.Language,
                    Score = 77.5
                }
            ...//more results
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().HasData(
                new Instructor() { InstructorId = 1, Name = "Jacques Alassane" },
                new Instructor() { InstructorId = 2, Name = "Alice des Plaines" }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstance>().HasData(
                new CourseInstance()
                {
                    CourseInstanceId = 1,
                    CourseModelId = 1,
                    InstructorId = 1,
                },
                new CourseInstance()
                {
                    CourseInstanceId = 2,
                    CourseModelId = 2,
                    InstructorId = 2,
                }
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<CourseGrade>().HasData(
                new CourseGrade()
                {
                    CourseGradeId = 1,
                    StudentId = 1,
                    CourseInstanceId = 1,
                    Grade = 75.3
                },
                new CourseGrade()
                {
                    CourseGradeId = 2,
                    StudentId = 1,
                    CourseInstanceId = 1,
                    Grade = 72.3
                }
                //more grades
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstanceStudent>().HasData(
                new CourseInstanceStudent() { CourseInstanceId = 1, StudentId = 1},
                new CourseInstanceStudent() { CourseInstanceId = 1, StudentId = 2},
                new CourseInstanceStudent() { CourseInstanceId = 2, StudentId = 1},
                new CourseInstanceStudent() { CourseInstanceId = 2, StudentId = 2}
            );
        }
```

Yet, when run add migration, update database, start up my app and hit `api/Students` (standard http get in postman), my `Student`s do not have any `Result`s. Nor any of the other entities in the collection that I meant to seed for that matter. What did I miss?

**EDIT**

To clarify more, my api:

```cs
// StudentsController.cs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _context.Students.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Where I call it in the front end

```cs
//StudentService.cs

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudentsAsync()
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };
            return await http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Student>>("api/Students", options);
        }
```

The response:

```
{"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","studentId":1,"name":"Camille Foussoulou","highSchoolRegistrationModelId":1,"highSchoolRegistrationModel":null,"currentGradeLevel":1,"guardians":null,"results":null,"courses":null,"courseGrades":null,"reportCards":null},{"$id":"3","studentId":2,"name":"Lucas Foussoulou","highSchoolRegistrationModelId":1,"highSchoolRegistrationModel":null,"currentGradeLevel":1,"guardians":null,"results":null,"courses":null,"courseGrades":null,"reportCards":null}]}
```

The commmands I ran

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c HighSchoolContext
dotnet ef database update -c HighSchoolContext
```

Using Sqlite at the moment.
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Can you post HighSchoolRegistrationModel class too, pls?

Comment: Do your migrations contain any `.InsertData(..)`? What about querying your tables directly?

Comment: @Serge I posted it

Comment: @JeremyLakeman It does, and they correspond to my .HasData() seeding in the context class. Querying the table directly? For instance, when I hit api/Students it queries the Students table and results are null

Comment: The basics of troubleshooting, narrow down where the problem is. Did the upgrade run successfully against this database? i.e. Use your database provider tools (eg "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio") to query the actual database tables.

Comment: You're trying to claim that the data doesn't exist. Your evidence is that your api doesn't return anything. But you haven't provided your api implementation.

Comment: I added more information about what I did. I am using Sqlite which is really just making a database file. I just sort of keep running add migrations and update database when I make changes. Sometimes I seem to run into caching issues which lead me to just delete all the migrations and start over-which I know isn't good practice but it's a personal project I can just blow up at my leisure

Comment: But yeah, you're right it seems like I might need to look into the migrations themselves as this could be an Sqlite thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237060/discussion-between-amdorsey12-and-jeremy-lakeman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had simply forgotten to define what related data I wanted included with the entity I was reading from the database. In this example, to get the `Result`s of the `Student` I just did this

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _context.Students
                    .Include(s => s.Results)
                    .ToListAsync();
        }
```

Which is eager loading, as I go on I'll probably explore [different loading strategies.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)